# NHibernate throwing "Unable to resolve property:", but property doesn't exist *ANYWHERE* in project

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm getting a weird issue with nHibernate... I'm getting this exception:

```
Unable to resolve property: _Portal
```

when I try to commit an object graph.  The strange thing is that when I search through the entire solution, I don't seem to have this particular property *ANYWHERE* within the project?!

Has anyone run into this particular case, and if so, what did they do to resolve?

Comment: I guess you know which of your entities is problematic so how is that entity, mapping, and db table schema looks like?

Comment: @nemesv It's an object graph... approximately 8 object types with 6 *.hbm.xml files... should I post all here?

Comment: Possibly a stupid comment, but when you searched through the entire project, did you make sure your file mask was * . * and not just *.cs or something more restrictive?

Comment: I'm in C# using VS.Net, and I've done it through the "entire solution" as well as "just these open documents" focusing on the classes in the graph.  I am thinking after looking at something I found the issue.  Just hoping it's not that stupid!

Comment: Do you have a backing field called _Portal on your domain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've ran into the same issue after upgrading nHibernate to 3.3 (from 3.1), as well as associated libraries (including FluentNhibernate). I have a parent object with a child collection, and when modifying the child collection, it would throw the same exception you received (with the nonexistant "_Namespace" property name, where "Namespace" was the first section of my actual namespace).

In our case, switching to SaveOrUpdate() is not an option, as we actually have a version of this object loaded in session as well, so we need Merge().

I don't know what other similarities there might be. For us it's a parent object with a child collection, using FluentNhibernate. Mapping on the parent object is Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan() for the child, and for the child to the parent, Cascade.None().

Unfortunately I can't find any other reports of this bug, so the solution for us was to just revert back to nHibernate 3.1 (and the associated binaries, like FluentNhibernate and Iesi.Collections). That's the only change, and then it works fine again.

**Update on bug logged in JIRA [3234].**

There is a bug logged for this in JIRA. The issue has not received any priority yet. Perhaps if you are experiencing this issue you can create an account and *vote for the bug to be fixed*.
https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3234

**Update on workaround posted for bug JIRA [3234].**

As per Ondrej's comment on the bug, overriding the default merge listener on the session configuration with this code solves the issue for now. I am sure with the workaround posted it will be fixed officially soon.

```
public class UniDirectionalMergeFixListener : DefaultMergeEventListener
{
    protected override IDictionary GetMergeMap(object anything)
    {
        var cache = (EventCache)anything;
        var result = IdentityMap.Instantiate(cache.Count);

        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in cache)
            result[entry.Value] = entry.Key;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Heh.. unfortunately, the project I'm using NHibernate for is the first deployable project I've done with the tool.  I hasn't realized that you can't do a SaveOrUpdate() when you have an object in memory.  Thus far, it seems to be working for me.

Comment: and so the pain came into play... I can't get a deep object graph to "clone" and then subsequently "save".  Need to figure this out.

Comment: Yeap... looks like I'm rolling back.

Comment: This just saved me more time. Thank you. Brain == fried

Comment: For a workaround please see my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21159718/143509

Answer (score 1):

So I solved my issue, but I'm not sure why this was the resolution.

In my project, I've abstracted out the use of nHibernate to be in its own project (*.Objects.nHibernate is the namespace).  I did this because the client I work with doesnt' typically like using nHibernate, and I'm trying to get them onboard with using it.

What was happening is that this project has a few data models that are append only in the system... e.g., we never do an update.  So, my "Repository" has to take that into account.

In my Commit() function within the repository, I serialize the object graph and then deserialize it to make a copy of the object for saving.  What I was doing was saying to the session "_Session.Merge(...)", when I needed to say "_Session.SaveOrUpdate(...)" to get things to commit to the database properly... unsure why that made a difference, but that was the answer to the past two days.

Thx. for your help Rippo & Nickolay!

Answer (score 1):

The workaround for this issue is to derive from DefaultMergeEventListener and override the following method like so:

```
    protected override IDictionary GetMergeMap(object anything)
    {
        var cache = (EventCache) anything;

        var result = IdentityMap.Instantiate(cache.Count);

        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in cache)
        {
            result[entry.Value] = entry.Key;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Then simply use this custom event listener when you construct your SessionFactory. I have posted additional details to the related NHibernate bug report: [NH-3234](http://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3234)

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check:-

1. Do you have a backing field called _Portal on your domain?
2. Also does the WORD `portal` exist anywhere within your solution?
3. Do a clean solution and see what DLL's are left in any of your BIN folders.
4. Is your NHibernate configuration being serialized after it has been built? If so check you are using the latest version.

HTH

Comment: 1) one of the namespaces is Portal.*, but no backing fields called _Portal. 2) See #1. 3) a "clean" cleans the entire project.  no files left.  4) I'm using the latest version from nuget.

Answer (score 0):

One more idea. NHibernate allow you to specify in mapping how to access your backing field or property. For example `<property access="nosetter.pascalcase-underscore" name="Timestamp" />` will make NHibernate to set value through field _Timestamp. Do you have such access specifiers in your mapping?

Comment: No... I'm not doing anyting using the Access attributes against any "properties" within the solution.